# XML empty element as boolean true

Tags: xsd

What issues, if any, are there from defining an XML empty element to mean true in an XML schema rather than using the built in boolean type?

E.g. representing true as

```
<myoption /> vs <myoption>true</myoption>
```

And representing false as

```
'myoption' element absent vs <myoption>false</myoption>
```

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

From a database point of view null is neither true nor false.

What about

```
<myoption state="true" />
<myoption state="false" />
```

?

Comment: What pros and cons are there with this approach vs others?

Comment: @Howard I admit there's no real pro to this approach other than explictly setting a value instead of assuming a missing value means `false` ... and your schema will be clearer.